# PyInstaller not bundling resources

Tags: pyinstaller

Why is it that using the flag --add-data, or setting in spec file "**datas=[]**" only copies the resources to the dist folder and not embed/bundle them?

Suppose I have a "**main.txt**" file (*let's assume there are confidential details in it*) and would like the file/resource to be bundled  in the executable. Why is that it **only gets copied to the dist dir instead**?

Here's the sample spec file >>

**...
datas=[('main.txt', '.')]**

Here's the freeze command >>

**pyinstaller main.spec --clean**